# What software tool should I use to draw graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software

I am writing a latex document, and I have a technical lemma that I would like to illustrate with an image.

The field is graph theory, and the lemma has several cases, so I want to draw a chart detailing the cases and to draw a picture of a graph for each case. The image has to be jpg or some other format that latex can handle, because I want to embed it in the document.

What would be a good software tool to do such a thing?

Comment: How many nodes/edges are in your graphs?  Are they small like a dozen or large like thousands?

Comment: You could use Matlab I guess. But I don´t anything specific about that.

Comment: Ask at [softwarerecs.SE] or [tex.SE], not here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [TikZ examples of graphs](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/), you can also just draw it in LaTeX :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Wolfram Mathematica is a good software to do some graphs. I think matlab will do that for your purpose too!

Comment: I think the OP refers to [these "graphs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: oh, ok!! I thought about graphs~plots...